# Evaluate XPath expression at runtime or use a different approach?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

```
<grid>
<col>Links</col>
<col>Rechts</col>
<row>
    <Links>l1</Links>
    <Rechts>r1</Rechts>
</row>
<row>
    <Links>l2</Links>
    <Rechts>r2</Rechts>
</row>
</grid>
```

Hey folks, given the XML data above I want to create a table like:

```
Links|Rechts
l1|r1
l2|r2
```

My XSL Template is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"
extension-element-prefixes="dyn">

    <xsl:template match="grid">

        <xsl:for-each select="//row">
            <xsl:variable name="currentrow" select="."/>
            <xsl:for-each select="//col">
                <xsl:variable name="colname" select="text()"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="dyn:evaluate('$currentrow/$colname/text()')"></xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The only output I get is "".

I Have no clue how to solve my issue. I dont event know, whether its the right way to use dyn:evaluate.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the shortest -- as number of templates or number of lines -- complete solution, that is resilient to missing `col` elements or to their order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="vColNames" select="/grid/col"/>
    <xsl:template match="grid">
        <table>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="col"/>
    <xsl:template match="col[1]">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../col" mode="wrap"/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="col" mode="wrap">
        <th>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </th>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="row">
        <xsl:variable name="vCurrent" select="."/>
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="$vColNames">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$vCurrent/*[name()=current()]"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="row/*">
        <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Links</th>
        <th>Rechts</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>l1</td>
        <td>r1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>l2</td>
        <td>r2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Note**: Iterate over the columns' names in `row` context.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you tell me how to remove all spaces in each element in $vColNames?

Comment: @markusf: You are welcome. Are you saying that you have some elements like `<col>  Rechts </col>`?

Comment: Alejandro, kinda. For example: "Col Name"

Comment: @markusf: Ah! You meant a value that it's not the name of any element. If posible, you must to make them match like stripping white space or replacing it by hypen.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your XSLT `grid` part with

```
<xsl:template match="grid">
    <xsl:for-each select="row">
            <xsl:value-of select="Links"/>|
            <xsl:value-of select="Rechts"/><br>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I have used `<br>` for a newline, if this is not HTML, use relevant symbol(s).

Comment: You haven't mentioned in your question this needs to use any dynamic: stuff. Mine (and I believe Tomalak's) code just works. Is that not what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="grid">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="col" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="row" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="col|row/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="position() = last()"><xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'" /></xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>|</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notes

- no dynamic evaluation of XPath is necessary for this.
- `<xsl:strip-space elements="*">` removes whitespace-only text nodes that would otherwise appear in the output
- the same template can match different nodes (here via the union operator `|`)
- this solution can cope with any number of columns
- it does not matter how the data fields are named since I used `row/*`

---

EDIT A more elaborate version that does not assume every column would be there.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="grid">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="col" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="row" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="col">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:call-template name="separator" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:variable name="this" select="." />
    <xsl:for-each select="/grid/col">
      <xsl:value-of select="$this/*[name() = current()]" />
      <xsl:call-template name="separator" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="separator">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="position() = last()"><xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'" /></xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>|</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, it works, now I'm trying to understand it. Ah ok, its pretty easy. But it does not work, if some cols are missing in a row. I have to check my data model, if that could be the case.

Comment: @markusf: This is correct assuming columns' names match every field and they do it in the exact order.

Comment: @markusf If that's the case, things would get a little more complicated. If you need a solution that matches column names to columns, that would be possible, too.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation** (having the smallest number of templates -- just 3, and shorter than all other current solutions, and resilient to element order or missing `col` elements):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="col[not(position()=last())]">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'|')"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="row">
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/col"
       mode="buildCell">
   <xsl:with-param name="pRow" select="."/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="col" mode="buildCell">
   <xsl:param name="pRow"/>

   <xsl:value-of select=
    "concat($pRow/*[name()=current()],
            substring('|', (position()=last())+1)
           )
    "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<grid>
    <col>Links</col>
    <col>Rechts</col>
    <row>
        <Links>l1</Links>
        <Rechts>r1</Rechts>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Links>l2</Links>
        <Rechts>r2</Rechts>
    </row>
</grid>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
Links|Rechts
l1|r1
l2|r2
```